# create 3d viewer and configurator for products on the website

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk, autodesk-model-derivative, autodesk-designautomation

i want to create a 3d Viewer and configurator for our products on our website. 
products are furniture and are mainly designed in Autodesk Inventor.
i wonder to have a dynamic configurator for products that users can change its dimension, materials, and colors (textures) and if possible include some products in one document.
something like iAssembly and iCopy features in Autodesk Inventor.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use the forge-viewer, but limited to only pre-canned geometry (no real-time geometry modification), material changes, colors (keynote photo of Jeldwen configuration webpage):

[image]

[YouTube-Demo](https://youtu.be/lNlG00ZVUyI?t=4541)

Here is a sample repo of a fusion360 chair using the Forge-Viewer: https://github.com/wallabyway/fusion-chair-configurator

A second option, if you have geometry modification, is to try the push-button solution: https://configurator360.autodesk.com